# Creating dynamic Hyperlink through C# code works in IE but not in Chrome

Tags: c#, dynamic, hyperlink

I am trying to read a folder from my local repository and I want to show the PDF file on my browser.
And when somebody clicks on that browser, one should be able to see the PDF file.

I am creating a dynamic link to that PDF but the problem is that when I click those links created dynamically in Chrome it does not do anything. But in IE it works fine, but it asks me to enable the intranet settings.

Code I am using to do this is below:

```
String link = "D:\\MyDir\\";
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("D:\\MyDir");
FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.pdf");
foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles) 
{
    Response.Write("<br><" + "a href=" +link+ fi.Name.ToString() + " runat= server >" + fi.Name.ToString() + "</a>");   
}
```

Comment: what version of IE are you using? I doubt if this will work in IE8+. I think most browsers have disabled support for direct filesystem urls. 
Besides the file path should be - file:///D:/mydir/a.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I thing your proplem is place of variable in string.

try this

```
string aLink = string.Format(@"<br/><a href=""{0}"" runat=""server"" >{1}</a>",link+ fi.Name.ToString(),fi.Name.ToString());
```

Comment: I tried this also still not working in Crome. I am using IE9 and it ask me to enable the intranet and as soon as I click on yes everything runs fine. But it does not work with crome.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the problem is the url is not enclosed in quotes, try changing the code to

```
Response.Write("<br><a href=\"" +link+ fi.Name.ToString() + "\" runat= server >" + fi.Name.ToString() + "</a>");
```

**EDIT** there is a limitation in google chrome which prevents you from opening local files because of security reasons, but there is an [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locallinks/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida) LocalLinks which allows you to do that

Comment: When I take my mouse on the links, in google crome on the left bottom corner it shows the link as  file:///D:/mydir/anyfile.pdf

But when I click on that it does not do anything, also when I right click and copy the link address it copies the exact address but I dont know why It does not react. Is there any way we cam implement this using handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Is the runat=server needed in this case? You are just creating a static link.

```
Response.Write("<br/><a href='" +link+ fi.Name.ToString() + "' target='_blank'>" + fi.Name.ToString() + "</a>");
```